# Is the description for 'Moderation' on the privs page accurate?

Tags: feature-request, privileges, privileges-page

I just noticed this block of text on [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) in the right coluomn.

> #### Moderation
>
> Help decide what questions and answers float to the top or participate in suggesting new features.

*...or participate in suggesting new features.* What??? Since when is suggesting a new feature *moderation*? If anything, it would fit in with either **Communication** or **Creation**:

> #### Communication
>
> Communicate with fellow users in chat rooms, meta-discussion, and comments, *or participate in suggesting new features.*

The [participate in meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilige is categorized as a Communication privilege.

> #### Creation
>
> Create questions, answers, tags, and other content, *or participate in suggesting new features*.

Either way, suggesting new features sure ain't moderation.

Request: **Take out the notion that suggesting new features is moderation.**

Comment: How is suggesting new features not (community-)moderation? Anything that helps improve or maintain site quality, or helps shape the site as such, in my view can be seen as moderation. Moderation is not merely "what a moderator does".

Comment: @Bart With that definition, answering questions is moderation. It helps maintain site quality.

Comment: That I would keep under "creation". It creates new content. That this content can be quality content is true, but that requires a vetting process by the community to establish that. The creation of content itself I would not see as moderation. What happens to that content afterwards is.

Comment: @Bart Then suggesting new features is also creation. It requires a vetting process by the community to establish its quality as a suggestion. The creation of content itself I would not see as moderation. *</plagiarism >*

Comment: Something tells me we're not going to agree on this one. ;)

Comment: @Bart Agree to disagree? :)

Comment: +1 But I think that the phrasing is just a way to include "participate in Meta" as a moderation privilege, which I think is correct. What is incorrect is that participating in Meta is not just about suggesting new features, and this specific action is arguably not a "moderation" action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, *strictly-speaking* privileges like "create tag synonyms", "edit questions and answers" and "vote up/down" aren't moderation - they're *[curation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curation)*.

But four tabs is probably enough, dontcha think?

Comment: People are [obsessed with word definitions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187871) today.

Comment: The "participate in meta" privilege was moved to the Communication tab; the "participate in suggesting new features" bit of the Moderation description seems to have gotten less accurate since this was posted. (Came from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190570/wording-on-moderation-privileges-description-is-highly-inaccurate which is marked as a duplicate even though when *this* one was asked the wording actually made sense...)