# Wording on moderation privileges description is highly inaccurate

Tags: bug, privileges, wording

When looking at the privileges page, we can see:

> ### Moderation
>
> Help decide what questions and answers float to the top or participate in suggesting new features.

That's hardly what moderation is about. The first part is borderline, but what does suggesting new features have to do with moderation?

Comment: Yes, moderation to me means "consuming substances in a controlled, responsible, and non-excessive manner"

Comment: The first part isn't especially borderline, since the upvote and downvote privs are listed in that section, but unless the wording of the second part was supposed to only appear on Meta, I can't even imagine what they intended.